# How prove this Pedoe inequality $a^2_{1}(b^2_{2}+c^2_{2}+d^2_{2}-a^2_{2})+b^2_{1}(a^2_{2}+c^2_{2}+d^2_{2}-b^2_{2})+\cdots\ge 16F_{1}F_{2}$

Tags: geometry, inequality

**Question:**

let $A_{i}B_{i}C_{i}D_{i}(i=1,2)$ be two quadrilaterals,and let $$B_{i}C_{i}=a_{i},C_{i}D_{i}=b_{i},D_{i}A_{i}=c_{i},A_{i}B_{i}=d_{i},i=1,2$$
and let $F_{i}$ denote the areas of $A_{i}B_{i}C_{i}D_{i}(i=1,2)$

show that:
$$a^2_{1}(b^2_{2}+c^2_{2}+d^2_{2}-a^2_{2})+b^2_{1}(a^2_{2}+c^2_{2}+d^2_{2}-b^2_{2})+c^2_{1}(a^2_{2}+b^2_{2}+d^2_{2}-c^2_{2})+d^2_{1}(a^2_{2}+b^2_{2}+c^2_{2}-d^2_{2})+4a_1b_2c_1d_2+4a_2b_1c_2d_1\ge 16F_{1}F_{2}$$

I know this **Pedoe inequality：**

let $a,b,c,a',b',c'$ denote the sides of triangles $ABC,A'B'C'$ and let $F$ and $F'$ denote their areas.then we have
$$a'^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)+b'^2(a^2+c^2-b^2)+c'^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)\ge 16FF'$$
for this inequality proof can see:[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedoe%27s_inequality) also can see:

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=2958

But for the  two quadrilaterals I can't prove it.maybe have some paper reserch this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my problem in the KöMaL magazine. See the solution at
http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=feladat&f=A586&l=en